# python print a line, if and only if x and y are found

Tags: python

I'm trying to print a line that contains specific keywords, and they both should be in the same line in order for it to print out.

This is how I approached the problem, I  made 2 variables and assigned them with the variables. One of them is a filename and that changes every time the program iterated through a list.

```
for files in myfiles:
       for lines in info:
             if dir_key and files in lines:
                      print lines
             else:
                 print "line not found"
```

This works, but the problem is, it also prints a line that only contains the filename. How do I ensure it doesn't do that ?. I tried the

```
if line.beginswith(dir_key) and line.endswith(file)
```

but that yielded no results what so ever. so I switched to the first method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
if dir_key in lines and files in lines:
```

if dir_key is a string, then the test `if dir_key:` will be `True` as long as `dir_key` isn't an empty string.  so your total test is most likely equivalent to `if True and (files in lines):`

Answer (score 2):

What you have right now is checking the [truthiness](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) of `dir_key`, not that `dir_key` is in `lines`. Change

```
if dir_key and files in lines:
#to
if dir_key in lines and files in lines:
```